# Creating a new date in Java using ints

Tags: java

I am currently using a `Date Picker`, to display/select a date. I am just having trouble with the format. below is how the example constructed it.

```
 new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
.append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
.append(" ").toString();
```

I don't want this format so I tried the following but it keeps giving the incorrect year even if the values are correct so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
Date date = new Date(year,month,day);
dates.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
```

for example if the date was 6 November 2015(current date) and I change it to 6 December 2015 it will display 6 December 3915
The following values are being returned year = 2015 month = 11 day = 6
And this Creates 6 December 3915 I don't understand why the year is not displaying properly if I choose 2016 it would be 3916

Comment: Incomplete question: post all your code. Having a dataFormat object and a date object alone ... doesn't really tell us what you did to turn the string into a date object. And unless you have requirements that dont allow for that; you really want to look into the Java8 stuff for date/time; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/

Comment: what do you think `d MMMM yyyy` will do?

Comment: Which date picker?  It's likely you need to supply the format directly to the picker so it can format the values itself

Comment: @Jägermeister the problem is actually in the deprecated `Date` constructor the OP is using so the question is actually complete. +1 for using java8 stuff (or joda-time).

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour can be expected actually. This is what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) says about the `Date` constructor you are using (emphasis added by me):

> `public Date(int year, int month, int day)`
>
> **Deprecated**. instead use the constructor `Date(long date)`
>   Constructs a Date object initialized with the given year, month, and day.
>
> The result is undefined if a given argument is out of bounds.
>
> Parameters:
>       year - **the year minus 1900**; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)
>       month - 0 to 11
>       day - 1 to 31

So you get 3915 because 2015 + 1900 = 3915

I recommend you don't use this constructor. First of all it is marked as deprecated. Most importantly, no person in his right mind would see an argument `int year` in a method and think *"Of course I have to subtract 1900 from the value I pass"*

The `LocalDate` introduced in Java 8 is recommended as a replacement. You would use it like this

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 6);
dates.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: what would u recommend I use instead ?

Comment: @CharlPotgieter added a recommendation. If you can't use Java 8 have a look at Joda-time that has similar API

Answer (score 0):

the format you are using is wrong. try this instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM YYYY");
```

Comment: my format is fine. current date is using that format and it displays fine. my app crashes when I use ur format..

Comment: You should use lowercase y `"dd MM yyyy"` uppercase  `Y` indicate "Week year"